# pass complex datatype from c# to fortran dll

Tags: c#, fortran

i have a subroutine in fortran 77 with input of complex data type .I created dll of fortran and added dll to c# project.

how i pass complex datatype to fortran dll?

is there any complex type library that compatible with fortran?(i use complex type of math.net library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably create the complex data type as a struct (and all the other complex sub-types) (rather than a class).  This will mean it's a data only DTO.  There may be extra things you need to do to align things on the correct boundaries but there are suitable attributes for this sort of thing.

Comment: tnx.that's mean i should create complex type manually with struct? does not exist ready library for this?

Comment: Are you able to call a simple Fortran function that doesn't take any parameters?  (i.e. are you able to call Fortran from C# at the moment)

Comment: i didn't think about it.i can call function with parameters.is this related to problem?

Comment: If you can call a function with parameters, then it sounds like an alignment difference between how C# aligns data compared to how Fortran aligns data.  Which Fortran compiler are you using?

Comment: hmm.i got it. i used intel visual fortran to create dll.i don't want to manipulate fortran file.i have equivalent library in c# and i want to compare results of fortran dll.

Comment: tnx alot again.